# Sum or average in plot_ly chart R

Tags: r, plotly

```
city_data <- tribble(
            ~City, ~Value,
            "Mumbai", "100",
            "Delhi", "200",
            "Mumbai", "150",
            "Delhi", 250
)

plot_ly(x = city_data$City, y = city_data$Value, type = "bar")
```

The following code produced the below chart
[image]

As you may notice, Delhi is displayed as 250 - the last Delhi's entry in tibble, Mumbai 150 - last for Mumbai.

Question

What I would like to have is a sum of City values instead of last value.
As such, Delhi would be 450 (200 + 250) and Mumbai 250 (100 +150).

I want to know is there any argument (specifically) in plotly package to get this result.

Notes based on my research:-

1. In ggplot I can use stat_sum argument to achieve this.
2. I can use table or any other function to rearrange the data and get required format.
3. I may even opt for an average by just changing the argument.

Comment: In your sample data you a mix of strings and numbers in your `Value`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about combining `ggplot` with `Plotly`?

```
library('tibble')
library('plotly')

city_data <- tribble(
  ~City, ~Value,
  "Mumbai", 100,
  "Delhi", 200,
  "Mumbai", 150,
  "Delhi", 250
)

g <- ggplot(city_data, aes(City)) + geom_bar(aes(weight = Value))
ggplotly(g)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will check it and let you know in case it fulfills my requirement.